# How to use Transactions in ASP.NET MVC identity 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

In My ASP.NET MVC5 Identity 2 Application trying to use transactions but it is not working.please see the below code the transactions not working.If `var saveteacher = _teacherService.Create(aTeacher);` not insert successfully then AspNetUsers not rollback from database.

Code:

```
using (var  dataContext = new SchoolMSDbContext())
{
  using (var trans = dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
  {
    try
    {
      var adminresult =await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, teacherViewModel.Password);
      if (adminresult.Succeeded)
      {
        aTeacher.Id = user.Id;
        var saveteacher = _teacherService.Create(aTeacher);
      }
      else
      {
        trans.Rollback();
        ModelState.AddModelError("", adminresult.Errors.First());
        return View();
      }
      trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      trans.Rollback();
      Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks legit. Did you step through the code in debugger? Is `trans.Rollback()` ever called on error?

Comment: no :( but catch throw Exception ex {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}  which i did for testing

Comment: where is this thrown from? you have 3 places in you code that can throw this exception, all of them are wrapped in `try-catch`, but you do `Rollback` in the catch. Is this rollback not executed?

Comment: no catch 'Rollback' do nothing !  I test it without  UserManager.CreateAsync and use another model like class and it worked. i don't know why UserManager.CreateAsync(...) not working !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem could be with async stuff.

Try creating the transaction like this:

```
TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
```

(you'll have to add `System.Transactions`) to references.

To commit transaction go `transaction.Complete()` to rollback do `transaction.Dispose()`.

Comment: Awesome ! It Worked ! But i have question : If i remove async stuff then still my previous code not working.why?.Anyway i update my code as you said and now it's working.Thanks :)

Comment: Identity by default is working in async. And the sync methods are just wrappers for async code. So if you add transactions on top, async nature comes out.

Comment: Thanks @trailmax your following statement is so helpful
"Identity by default is working in async. And the sync methods are just wrappers for async code."

Comment: transaction.dispose() for rollback? Not sure, if that is right, because you have to dispose the transaction anyway!
The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown, Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @Legends No, you don't have to explicitly call `Dispose`. Using `using` statement with transaction scope is good enough. See code sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a new instance of SchoolMSDbContext when you should be acquiring the existing one from the HttpContext.

Example:

```
using (var  dataContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
    {
      //...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `_teacherService` and `UserManager` uses same DB Context. No need to create a TransactionScope.